# Can you get ERB to properly indent when rendered?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb, indentation

I have several partials that I'm including in my Rails `application.html.erb file`, but the resulting HTML doesn't preserve my indenting (formatting). I've been told that the first line gets rendered with the same indentation-level as the call to `_partial.html.erb`, but all subsequent lines in the partial just get left-aligned.

This results in code like (see my comments for positioning):

```
<body>
    <div id="outer">

        <div class="contentwidth main">
            <div class="logo"> <<<<< Shouldn't be this far to the right
    <h1><a href="index.html">minimal.</a></h1>
</div><!-- end logo -->     <<<<<<< Shouldn't be way over to the left
```

Is there any way to fix this/format my included partials better using ERB? Or do I need to use HAML?

Comment: Why do you care? HTML is for machine consumption, not human consumption.

Comment: It bothers me and properly-nested tags look much better from an organization perspective (easier to see where content begins and ends).

Comment: Humans have to consume things meant for machines when debugging.

Comment: You can "view source" to look at the HTML if necessary but you'll have better luck with a decent DOM inspector (such as Firebug or WebKit's "inspect element").

Comment: I know I can use another tool to clean up the mess. I'm just wondering if there's some **Rails secret** I don't know about to avoid the hassle in the first place. I've seen other Rails websites with properly nested tags that use partials in the Views.

Comment: I will sometimes simply indent all of the code within the partial, so that it comes out clean where it is used.  That only works for partials that are always used in a few similarly-constructed pages though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [doc on filters](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html) contains an example of using an after filter to compress the html before sending it to the browser.

Doing something similar, but using something like [Tidy](https://rubyforge.org/projects/tidy/) to reformat and replace the html where this example does a compress might do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Not the answer you want - but - no, there's nothing built into Rails to auto-indent ERB.

Comment: Sadly this seems to be the case. I've switched to HAML and am loving every bit of it.

Comment: Yeah, haml is definitely worth switching to.