# Rails: how to output pretty html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, template-engine

I use SASS as views engine with built-in prettyfying option in `config/application.rb`:

```
Slim::Engine.set_default_options :pretty => true
```

Nevertheless, not only usage of `rdiscount` for posts rendering breaks all that beauty, but typical commands do that, e.g.:

```
title
  = "#{t "title.main"} - #{(yield :title) || "#{t "title.default"}"}"

== stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"
```

turns into

```
<title>Some title</title><link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

In additon, some examples of tags indentation:

```
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>...
    </header>
    <div class="content"><div class="posts"><article>
  <div class="title">
    <h3>...</h3>
    <h2>...</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="entry"><p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</article><article>
  <div class="title">
    <h3>...</h3>
    <h2>...</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="entry"><p>...</p>

    <p>...</p>

  </div>
</article><article>
```

Maybe there is some `after_filter` or whatever exist to prettify `responce.body` after all?

That `:pretty => true` will be disabled then because it does only a half of the work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you get ERB to properly indent when rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691653/can-you-get-erb-to-properly-indent-when-rendered)